# iOS 11.2 autocorrects French words when using English keyboard

Tags: keyboard, internationalization, language, autocorrect

Back in iOS 10, it was a new feature that words from a different language and be mixed in your primary language and wouldn't get autocorrected. And you can type the whole thing in that other language and it will actually help you put accent on these foreign words. Then in iOS 11 it all disappeared. Does anyone have a fix for this?

For this feature I am mentioning, we can see an article pointing it out here http://appleinsider.com/articles/16/06/22/inside-ios-10-multilingual-typing-eases-autocorrect-woes

Comment: You have only the English and French dictionaries checked in settings/general/dictionary?

Comment: Yes, only those two languages checked in the dictionaries. The thing is, I just upgraded to iOS 11 and unless some settings were reset during the installation, nothing else was touched. I really hope this feature hasn't been removed...